# Passing variable data into scss from twig

Tags: 8, theming

Is it possible to pass variable data from twig into css, like is done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893823/how-to-pass-parameters-to-css-classes) non drupal related question. The accepted answer suggests it's possible.

My Drupal project uses data from image fields to set the background image of page content.
Currently, I am achieving the desired effect by doing the following in my twig template:

```
<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--homepage-paragraph paragraph--view-mode--default paragraph--type--bg_img column"
     style="background-image: url(/sites/default/files/2020-08/publication_2.jpg);
     width: 171px;">
</div>
```

But, rather than set the image data as attributes, I am looking for a cleaner solution in which I can set the background in css with the url data passed in as a variable.

The linked question above suggests it's possible but when I try I get the following results in my markup inspector:
[image]

That's the result of amending my code above to the following:

```
<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--homepage-paragraph paragraph--view-mode--default paragraph--type--bg_img column"
     style="--image: url(/sites/default/files/2020-08/publication_2.jpg);
     --width: 171px;">
</div>
```

I'd appreciate any insights.

Comment: Does the width option work? It seems like this could be an issue specifically related to `url()`

Comment: From Twig into CSS? Certainly, you can write CSS and JS in Twig as well as plain HTML. I've done this in `html.html.twig.` to pass style overrides from user entities into CSS. From Twig into SCSS? Most likely not, because in PHP frameworks Sass compiiling is usually done once before deployment, and Twig is done on runtime.

Comment: It seems to me that you misunderstood the question / answer that you linked above. They are "injecting" the CSS variable in the same HTML page - not into a Twig template. I just wonder why you want to do so? Why do you think it is cleaner that way with a CSS variable instead the way you did it? As only the one paragraph should get this background image (I assume) I feel that this is a bit of overengineering